# Parsing namespace from SOAPClient Response

Tags: xml, soap, xml-namespaces, soap-client

OK so I have SOAPClient making a call. If I use __getLastResponse() I get a line in my XML like this:

```
<Discount xsi:type="ProgressivePromotion" from="2013-05-05T00:00:00" to="2013-05-14T00:00:00" type="Percent" value="20" name="Special Deal"/>
```

However, the function in my SOAPClient Class returns an object.

The code for the call in the PHP class is:

```
function SearchHotels($parameters ){
$funcRet = null;
try {
    $funcRet = $this->client->SearchHotels($parameters);
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "(SearchHotels) SOAP Error:\n-------------------------------------\n" . $e->getMessage () . "\n\n";
    echo "(SearchHotels) Request:\n-------------------------------------\n" . $this->client->__getLastRequest() . "\n\n";
    echo "(SearchHotels) Response:\n-------------------------------------\n" . $this->client->__getLastResponse() . "\n\n";
}
return $funcRet; 
}
```

When I use the object that is returned, I can access the following attributes from the Discount element as:

type: ProgressivePromotion
from: 2013-05-05T00:00:00
to: 2013-05-14T00:00:00
value: 20
name: Special Deal

But I can't access type="Percent"

It seems that SOAPClient disregards the xsi namespace in xsi:type and just stores that attribute as *type*.

So how can I access xsi:type AND type so I can tell if my discount is a Percent or Amount or whatever other type it could be?

BTW, at the top of my SOAP Response, I do not see ANYTHING declaring what xsi is.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SearchHotelsResponse xmlns="http://tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3">
            <SearchHotelsResult>
                <Info xmlns="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3" version="9.71" culture="en-US" serverTime="2013-02-06T14:49:58.3500117-05:00"/>
                   <HotelList xmlns="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3">
```

**EDIT**

If I var_dump the object returned, I get

```
stdClass Object
(
[SearchHotelsResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Info] => stdClass Object
            (
                [version] => 9.71
                [culture] => en-US
                [serverTime] => 2013-02-06T15:17:59.8445748-05:00
            )

        [HotelList] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Hotel] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            [RoomTypes] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [RoomType] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                       [Discount] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [from] => 2013-05-05T00:00:00
                                                                [to] => 2013-05-14T00:00:00
                                                                [type] => ProgressivePromotion
                                                                [value] => 20
                                                                [name] => Special Deal
                                                            )
```

See how I lost the type="Amount"?

I can't call Discounts by doing

```
echo $result->SearchHotelsResult->HotelList->Hotel[0]->RoomTypes->RoomType[0]->Discounts->type;
```

Because I get

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$Discounts  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

So I convert the whole object into a giant multidimensional array and access things that way. Regardless, the *type="Amount"* isn't being pulled.

Comment: `xsi` is declared right there in the second line: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. Could you provide the code you are using to access those attributes?

Comment: This is a namespace issue, client knows nothing about "http://tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3", thinks that there are two 'type' attributes and uses the last one. Do you have wsdl provided to your client? If not, then the namespace should be explicitly specified in the constructor's parameter array.

Comment: http://demo2.touricoholidays.com/THFwsV3/HotelFlow.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the problem this way.

```
<?php
class fixSoapClient extends SoapClient{
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $result = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
        $str = preg_replace('#<Discount xsi:type="ProgressivePromotion"(.+)type="(.+)"(.+)name="(.+)"/>#isU', 
                '<Discount xsi:type="ProgressivePromotion"$1type="wath ever"$3name="$2"/>', $result);
        return $str;
    }   
}
```

You will find the discount type in the name attribute.
So instead of instantiate `SoapClient` you have to instantiate `fixSoapClient`

Comment: Ok but xsi:type is not always going to be ProgressivePromotion. And your example replaces name= with ProgressivePromotion instead of the actual name ("Special Deal")

Comment: To make this more complicated, there might also be other attributes added such as pay= and stay=

Comment: No, xsi:type is always "ProgressivePromotion" (it is a ComplexType).
if you need the name attribute also, then, you can for example keep the name attribute value + '#' and then the discount type value, like this
name="Special Deal#Percent"
then you split by # (and you have both name&type)
you cannot add an extra attribute because the internal parser will check the xml with the xsd (and since the xsd don't define your extra attributes, they will not be recognized).

But i think you got the idea,

Comment: --This works and is acceptable but I'd like to see if anyone can share how to get the actual attributes before I give the bounty. This question can help a lot of people who deal with Namespace issues.

Comment: This is a bug in the internal parser, the provided solution is not really bad (it's a hack but a good hack).
the only other option to fix this problem is to use a 3rd party SoapCient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are parsing your response with a namespace aware XML parser but the namespace support of the parser isn't turned on. This results in a clash of two rules.

1. When parsing an XML document with namespaces, all elements and attributes are referred to with their expanded name. Expanded name consist of the namespace URI and the local name of the element/attribute. If the parser is not namespace aware, the URI part of the name is lost. Therefore some parsers with namespace support also drop the namespace prefix if the namespace support is not turned on.
2. An element is not allowed to contain two attributes with same (expanded) name. In such cases other one of the attributes is lost. Normally a namespace aware XML parser would see those two `type` attributes as `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type` and `type` (using James Clark notation). A non-namespace aware parser should return attribute names `xsi:type` and `type`. In these cases there is no name collision and everything should work ok.

Problems arise if your parser knows that a colon `:` works as a namespace prefix delimiter but the parser is not using namespaces and therefore drops the delimiter and the namespace prefix. Then both of these attributes will get name `type` and other one of these is lost/overwritten because of the attribute name uniqueness rule.

Solution: Set namespace support on for your parser or switch to another more capable parser. Hopefully someone can give more specific answers if you update your question with information on how the XML file is being parsed.

Comment: How the XML file is being parsed? I dont understand. I'm using SOAPClient as stated above. Is there another way?