# Soap PHP: Part of response not coming

Tags: php, soap, soapui

When I test request in SoapUI it looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <offers:getOffersResponse xmlns:offers="http://www.pontis.com/integration/common/offers/v1" xmlns:kartel-offers="http://www.pontis.com/integration/kartel/offers/v1" xmlns:common="http://www.pontis.com/integration/common/integration-common/v1">
         <common:result>
            <common:code>0</common:code>
         </common:result>
         <categories>
            <category id="myPromotion">
               <offers>
                  <offer id="DB-_Ui03_1966_3a8f1c986c_ca6aa">
                     <type>BAU</type>
                     <selectionMode>not-available</selectionMode>
                     <selectionParams>
                        <code>789</code>
                     </selectionParams>
                     <kartel-offers:digitalPresentationInfo>
                        <text>Vivamus, WEB Russian mea Lesbia, atque amemus, rumoresque senum severiorum omnes unius aestimemus assis!
soles occidere et redire possunt; nobis, cum semel occidit brevis lux, nox est perpetua una dormienda.</text>
                        <bannerId>catullus5_web.png</bannerId>
                     </kartel-offers:digitalPresentationInfo>
                     <kartel-offers:digitalOfferAdditionalInfo>
                        <shortDescription>one WEB RU of the most famous poems by Catullus</shortDescription>
                        <amount>25</amount>
                        <price>22</price>
                        <unitType>MINUTES</unitType>
                        <validity>29</validity>
                     </kartel-offers:digitalOfferAdditionalInfo>
                  </offer>
               </offers>
               <kartel-offers:digitalPresentationInfo>
                  <text>myPromotion</text>
               </kartel-offers:digitalPresentationInfo>
            </category>
         </categories>
      </offers:getOffersResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when I make call from php it misses some attributes (digitalPresentationInfo, digitalOfferAdditionalInfo etc.):

```
    stdClass Object ( [result]
 => stdClass Object ( [code]
 => 0 )
 [categories]
=> stdClass Object ( [category] 
=> stdClass Object ( [offers]
 => stdClass Object ( [offer]
 => stdClass Object ( [type]
 => BAU [selectionMode]
 => not-available [selectionParams]
 => stdClass Object ( [code]
 => 789 ) [id]
 => DB-_Ui03_1966_3a8f1c986c_ca6aa ) ) [id]
 => myPromotion ) ) )
```

Why attributes are missing during php call?

PHP Code:

```
$wsdlUrl = 'kartel/kartel-offers.wsdl';

$soapClientOptions = array(
    'exceptions'=>true,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'encoding'=>'utf-8'
);
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdlUrl,$soapClientOptions);
$params = [
    'msisdn' => '7773277581',
    'requestedOfferType' => 'bau',
    'language' => 'ru',
    'channel' => 'web'
];
$result = $client->getOffers($params);
print_r($result);
```

**UPD** 
PHP code (in html section) which makes soap call and XSD schema (in js section) : https://jsfiddle.net/j5v8eoyf/

Comment: These are in a different XML Namespace. When the response is converted to stdClass they seem not to be parsed. If you would share the code that creates that object from the response, one could probably say more.

Comment: @hakre code is there https://jsfiddle.net/j5v8eoyf/

Comment: Perhaps the definition for these in the response is missing so the the SoapClient drops them when turning the response into an object. This is a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14737719/367456 - albeit I don't like the accepted answer as it is only a work-around that is not portable.